# Node Js printing before execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver

I am using node Js for automation and its printing all the console.log statements in one go, even before the browser opens up. Basically i have a print statement(console.log) after each line of code to make sure that my code has been executed, however this node.js prints all the print statement in one go.... even before the browser fires up... and then throws exception-  element not found. How can i make sure that only after the code line has been executed, the next line executes ?? - below line of code, i am trying to execute...

Secondly, I am not able to make the script wait explicitly - in java there is a simple method `Thread.sleep(5000)` ... 
how does it work in Javascript?

var un =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userName']")).sendKeys('CIT.XXXX');
console.log("login text entered");
var pwd =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys('ABCD123!');
console.log('Password keys Sent');

var Login =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='smLogin']")).click();
console.log('Login Clicked');

Comment: Mind sharing your code? I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I agree with @senojoeht, more information is required. For example what has a browser to do with Node JS?

Comment: ooxi - node js webdriver is used for web automation..anyways, please can anyone guide me how to let my code wait for a certain amount of time in javascript webdriver please ?

Comment: Also, I am not sure what all to configure in node js while using it for automation.... i checked you tube as well however not much resources are available when it comes to javascript webdriver node js.... any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library for synchronous processing in javascript.

Reference: https://github.com/caolan/async